Proof Check: why am I not using the fact that the bi-invariant volume form is left invariant
Let $G$ be a connected and compact Lie group. I want to show that $G$ admits a bi-invariant Riemannian metric.
Here's the proof:
Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be the lie algebra and pick an arbitrary inner product $h$ on it. Using left translation, there exists a left-invariant Riemannian metric $\tilde{h}$ on $G$ whose value at the identity is $h$. For $v,w\in \mathfrak{g}$ I then define a smooth function $f_{v,w}:G\rightarrow\mathbb{R},g\mapsto h(Ad(g)v,Ad(g)w)$ and an inner product $\langle ,\rangle:\mathfrak{g}\times\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by setting
$$\langle u,v\rangle=\int_Gf_{u,v}\omega$$
where $\omega$ is the Riemannian volume form with respect to $\tilde{h}$. Since $G$ is compact and connected and $\tilde{h}$ is left invariant, this Riemannian volume form is bi-invariant. In particular $R_k^*\omega=\omega$ for any $k\in G$. Now, if $\langle , \rangle$ is $Ad$-invariant, then it induces a bi-invariant Riemannian metric on $G$. So that's what I'll show. First, for any $k\in G$, $$f_{Ad(k)v,Ad(k)w}(g)=h(Ad(g)Ad(k)v,Ad(g)Ad(k)w)=h(Ad(gk)w,Ad(gk)v)=f_{v,w}(gk)=f_{v,w}\circ R_k$$
So for any $v,w\in \mathfrak{g}$ and $k\in G$, we then obtain $$\langle Ad(k)v,Ad(k)w\rangle=\int_G (f_{v,w}\circ R_k)\omega=\int_G (f_{v,w}\circ R_k)R_k^*\omega=\int_G R_k^*(f_{v,w}\omega)=\int_G f_{v,w}\omega.$$
The last equality follows from the fact that $R_k$ is an orientation preserving diffeomorphism.
Here's my issue: in the proof for $Ad$-invariance, I only used the fact that $\omega$ is right invariant. And I don't understand where I went wrong. This implies that every compact Lie group admits a bi-invariant metric.
